# Limits for triple integral parabolic cylinder

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> Determine the volume bounded by the parabolic cylinder $z=x^2$ and the planes $y=0$ and $y+z=4$.

**My work**. I am not sure if I have the correct limits for this question. I used 
$x = -\sqrt{z},\dots, \sqrt{z}$,
$y= 0,\dots, 4-z$,
$z=0,\dots,4$.

It seems too easy, should I be using polars?

Comment: Please do not ask questions using pictures of text, since otherwise the question is difficult to search for and some users cannot see the pictures on some devices.

Comment: Fair question! (+1)

Comment: If it easy good for you! We don't really need polar in that case since for $z$ fixed the domain is rectangular.

Comment: I mean its a lot of marks and I felt I hadn't done enough work for it.

Comment: @Pumpkinpeach To avoid downvotes, let us know your progress. BTW please take a few minutes for a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @RobertZ That's a good advice but I don't think that the question posed was totally insufficient. The asker presented his work on that, even if in a short way. Anyway, I agree that the question can be improved adding some more detail abou the result obtained.

Comment: @gimusi I agree, but unfortunately this question got 3 downvotes.

Comment: @RobertZ Thise downvotes are not motivated in my opinion, even if I agree that the question can be improved, it doesn't deserve such kind of welcoming.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the limits are  correct, the volume is given by the following iterated integral
$$\int_{z=0}^{4}\left(\int_{x=-\sqrt{z}}^{\sqrt{z}}\left(\int_{y=0}^{4-z} dy\right) dx\right) dz.$$
Can you take it from here? Cartesian coordinates seems to be fine here.

Answer (score 1):

To check the set up we need to make some sketches of the domain as for example in $z-x$ and $z-y$ planes

[image]
and also important in the $x-y$ plane for $z$ fixed that is a rectangular domain

[image]

from here your set up seems correct.